# Connecting two computers directly using Fiber

Tags: networking, fibre-channel

At my workplace, we have an electron microscope that is hooked to our storage server using a 10g FC connection.

Due to unknown reasons, we are experiencing some issues with the connectivity. As plan B, I am thinking of moving the storage server near the equipment.

Given these facts, is it possible to connect to computers directly using LC-LC multimode patch [cables?](http://www.fs.com/products/41728.html?currency=USD&paid=google_shopping&gclid=CO7A6Oqtz9ECFZSPfgodQQMHcg)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this as long as both have compatible cards installed.